# Kiosk, no keyboard, need access to right click event

Tags: javascript, mouse

In a kiosk environment, where there is no keyboard, and only a device that the browsers sees as a 2 button mouse, I need access to the right mouse click. This is a custom application running in a browser against file://....  with no Internet access behind airport security.

The left button will increase by 1 a totals field. The intent for the right mouse button is to decrease by 1 the same totals field. There are dozens of such fields on the page.

If I turn off the context menu, I still don't get a click event on right mouse click, even though the Mozilla Developer site documents what I'm supposed to get. How can I gain access to the click event on right click?

I can't use double click on the left to signal the negative because we expect users to rapidly left click to run up totals per field. Having left double click mean negative wouldn't work.

Comment: Does your Kiosk support multitouch?

Comment: No multitouch. This is primitive. The mouse isn't even a mouse. It's some security gadget that the browser thinks is a mouse. It supports 2 buttons, not even a scroll wheel.

Comment: why not add a button that decreases the total, instead of trying to duplicate the RMB?  Most kiosks run under the assumption that a touch is LMB, and have no access to RMB.

Comment: @ FireCrakcer37 The field they click in has the total displayed. Left up, right down. It's intuitive. Adding a button spoils the effect.

Comment: What kiosk software are you running? What browser is installed there? Do you have access to the configuration of that kiosk?

Comment: @Zim84   I'm writing an application using pure JS. I'm not using any "Kiosk" software. The browsers I'm aiming at are Chrome & Firefox. I'm 100% Linux, so I have no access to IE, and airport security uses Firefox exclusively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set context to return false on the body, then add handlers to the elements you wish to handle. Bubbling.

```
<body oncontextmenu='return false' style='margin: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;'>

  <div style='width: 64px; height: 64px; background: rgb(44, 188, 44); position: absolute;' oncontextmenu='alert("Click!");'>

</body>
```

Comment: From your comment and the one from Toby, I think I understand the technique. Stop the context menu on the body but then start one on a div that wraps the entire page contents and sits just below the body. I hadn't thought of that. I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry - I should have put more style in there for the body. You want everything absolutely wrapped inside the body. The object will take focus over the body. The page should hopefully explain better than I: http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: Works great! Your short demo snippet above was helpful. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div oncontextmenu="javascript:alert('success!');return false;">
    Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

If you do not return false it will also open the normal right click menu

If you right click on the div it will perform the function you give it

Answer (score 1):

Use the `oncontextmenu` event and the `click` event. Link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EgL3R/

```
$('.area').click(function () {
    increment(this, 1);
}).bind('contextmenu', function () {
    increment(this, -1);
    return false;
});
```

Have fun :)